# Why "vie" selects the whole file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the vim plugin in VS Code.

I've noticed that `viw` can select a whole word ("inner word"), but by accident I typed `tie` and the whole file is selected. Any intuitive explanation for `vie`?

Comment: It doesn't do that for me. `vie` enters visual mode but doesn't select anything. I see help for `viw` under `:help v_iw`, but there's no `:help v_ie` entry.

Comment: Note that there's dedicated [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com). You might try asking over there if you don't get a good answer here.

Comment: may be you would have pressed ve . v -> visual mode e -> end of a word. You would have been in the beginning of the word. and you selected the whole word

Comment: "The whole text" means the entire file. By the way I'm using vim plugin on VS Code, and I'v tried "diw" and "ciw", whose results are both clearing the entired file. This behavior is wired.

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever for expecting any sequence of keystrokes to have the same behaviour in a Vim *emulator* as it does in Vim. If your Vim emulator acts weird, use their issue tracker.